# Symfony twig use keys in for loops

Tags: twig, symfony

Does somebody know an other way to do that with twig, because it returns me an error :/

```
{% for key, conversation in conversations %}
    {% set lastMessage = sortedConversations.key %}
    <p>{{ lastMessage }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Here is the error returned : 
Key "key" for array with keys "0" does not exist

Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure to understand, but may be you can try this:

```
sortedConversations[key]
```

instead of

```
sortedConversations.key
```

Comment: oh thank you ! I forgot that we could do that as well ! :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
{% for key, conversation in conversations %}
  {% set lastMessage = sortedConversations[key] %}
  <p>{{ lastMessage }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Note the brackets around `key`.
This way, twig should notice key as a variable and not as a simple string.

Comment: Sorry, obviously, we answer in the same time. I like your answer, so +1 :)